# Text of the preceding heading in word

Tags: vba, ms-word

Given any selected word or paragraph in Word, is there a way to use VBA to find the text of the nearest preceding heading?

For example:

Heading Level 1: The Main Title
 This is a paragraph about the document. (A)
Heading Level 2: A Sub Title
 This paragraph describes a detail.(B)

If any part of (B) is selected, I want to find "A Sub Title".  If any part of (A) is selected, I want to find "The Main Title".

Answer (score 3):

There is a special `WdGoToItem` towards the previous heading:

```vb
Dim heading As Range
Set heading = selection.GoTo(What:=wdGoToHeading, Which:=wdGoToPrevious)

' Display heading text
heading.Expand Unit:=wdParagraph
MsgBox heading.Text
```

Here is a little known trick to get the whole current heading level from anywhere within a document:

```vb
Dim headingLevel as Range
' headingLevel encompasses the region under the preceding heading
Set headingLevel = Selection.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\HeadingLevel")
```

Comment: This is neat. Just an addition to this... How do we get the section number along with the heading name? For example, my heading is "1.2.1 Heading Text". Your solution does get me the "Heading Text", but I need the full heading name. Any way to do that?

Comment: @Meet: I made the change to get the numbering string as well in [Determine current heading text and number for a Word comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30540683/1892560)

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Do
        Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1

        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend

        If ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber) = 1 Then Exit Do
    Loop Until Selection.Style <> "Normal"

    MsgBox Selection.Style
End Sub
```

**SANPSHOT**

[image]